# GStreamer: vorbis transmuxing (pass-through) and transcoding via parsebin

Tags: gstreamer, vorbis, transcode

Can anybody to help me with understand how I can to work with vorbis in Gstreamer via **parsebin** element ? In examples below I use matroska file with one video (h264) and one audio (vorbis) streams.

For example next case is **worked** (used auto****sink **w/o vorbisparse**):[image: used auto****sink w/o vorbisparse]

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location="h264.Vorbis.10sec.mkv" ! parsebin name=pb pb. ! queue ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert ! autovideosink pb. ! queue !               vorbisdec ! audioconvert ! autoaudiosink
```

---

but in this case all **hangs** (used auto****sink **with vorbisparse**)

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location="h264.Vorbis.10sec.mkv" ! parsebin name=pb pb. ! queue ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert ! autovideosink pb. ! queue ! vorbisparse ! vorbisdec ! audioconvert ! autoaudiosink
```

---

**worked** (used separate filesinks **with vorbisparse**):[image: used separate filesinks with vorbisparse]

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location="h264.Vorbis.10sec.mkv" ! parsebin name=pb pb. ! queue ! matroskamux ! filesink location=d:/v.mkv pb. ! queue ! vorbisparse ! matroskamux ! filesink location=d:/a.mkv
```

---

**hangs** (used separate filesinks **w/o vorbisparse**):

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location="h264.Vorbis.10sec.mkv" ! parsebin name=pb pb. ! queue ! matroskamux ! filesink location=d:/v.mkv pb. ! queue !               matroskamux ! filesink location=d:/a.mkv
```

---

**worked** (used multiqueue, **separate filesinks** and vorbisparse):[image: used multiqueue, separate filesinks and vorbisparse]

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location="h264.Vorbis.10sec.mkv" ! parsebin name=pb ! multiqueue name=mq   pb. ! mq.   mq.src_0 ! matroskamux name=mux ! filesink location="d:/v.mkv"   mq.src_1 ! vorbisparse ! matroskamux ! filesink location="d:/a.mkv"
```

---

**hangs** (used multiqueue, **single filesink** and vorbisparse):[image: used multiqueue, single filesink and vorbisparse]

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location="h264.Vorbis.10sec.mkv" ! parsebin name=pb ! multiqueue name=mq   pb. ! mq.   mq.src_0 ! matroskamux name=mux ! filesink location="d:/va.mkv"  mq.src_1 ! vorbisparse ! mux.
```

---

P.S. My main goal is to use this **parsebin** element and get the ability to transcode or transmux streams as needed. For example:

- video => transmux, audio => transmux
- video => transmux, audio => transcode
- video => transcode, audio => transmux
- video => transcode, audio => transcode

*I will be grateful for your clarifications and help*

Comment: If you want to get a test file, you can find it here: https://yadi.sk/d/XGPDawgc3NcpP5

Comment: I use GStreamer 1.12.2

Comment: Ever found an answer?